# App Engine Modules vs Multiple Scripts

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am developing with Python in App Engine and I understand what modules are from reading the [*documentation*](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/), but I thought mapping different URLs to different python scripts was the process of creating modules. I thought each script runs on its own when required, thus less bandwidth is used because the user is only accessing the required code instead of having one giant script that handles everything. Can someone please explain the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing whatsoever to do with bandwidth. Neither Modules nor separate scripts will affect bandwidth in any way: that is simply determined by how much data you transfer between Google and your users.

And separate scripts won't even really help with memory usage either: usually all the different scripts corresponding to separate routes are loaded at the start of the process and stay in memory for the duration of that process, which lasts for multiple requests.

But Modules in the App Engine sense are for a completely different purpose. As that documentation page you link to explains, they are to do with separating different parts of a large application into separate components. Unlike multiple scripts within a single module, code that is in separate modules could never be loaded into the same process. Another benefit is that you can have different performance profiles for different modules - for example, a backend module that allows long-running requests.